# How to stop iFrame video in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, iframe

I'm looking on how to stop an iFrame video with angular js !

I'm new to Angularjs and I'm not able to do that, I could do that with jQuery :

```
 var TheFrame;
$(document).on( "pagebeforehide", function( event, data ) { 
    TheFrame = $(event.target).find("iframe");
    setTimeout(StopVideo, 500);
});

function StopVideo(){
    var vid  = TheFrame.prop("src");
    TheFrame.prop("src", "");
    TheFrame.prop("src", vid);    
}
```

So if you have an idea on how to do that when clicking on button for example that would be great

Comment: Show us complete code or create a plunkr ..

Comment: You should encapsulate those operations inside a directive.